# Indentation of pp-symbols in Fortran with or without -traditional option

Tags: gcc, fortran, comments, indentation, c-preprocessor

I am currently working on cleaning up a huge legacy program written in Fortran and preprocessed with '-traditional'.

I am aware that this seems to be the common way to do it. However the code is peppered with lots and lots of pp symbols ('#define', '#ifdef' and such) which completely break the indentation and make it very hard to read and understand 10s of thousands of lines of code written by multiple other authors over decades. Since my main task is to  enhance the readability and maintainability of the code, I'd love to indent those while cleaning up. Sadly, this seems to be impossible with '-traditional'.

Afaik the main reason for using '-traditional' with Fortran is comment handling. the Fortran concatenation symbol '//' is a line comment in c and  is therefore removed by cpp, thus breaking the code. I'm aware of the -c or -cc options but since this program is using some external libraries with c-style block comments ('/* */') this won't work either. There's also c-style block comments within the source, which i could replace with line comments, but I can't change the style of comment in the external libraries.

Is there any way to make Fortran code with c-style block comments work without '-traditional'? 
Or alternatively: is there any way to make indentation of pp symbols work with '-traditional'?

*edit*:
The code is usually compiled with gfortran. But compatibility with Solaris Studio is required too.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning somewhere you are interested in [tag:gfortran], many other compilers use [tag:fpp], a different similar preprocessor (which has similar limitation).

Comment: Do you have to apply the `-C` or `-CC` flag to all pre-processed files?

Comment: I do not have to, but I'd want to in every file where the indentation is broken due to the pp-symbols. Which is almost every file. Concatenations are equally common.

Comment: If you require also compatibility with Solaris Studio, which uses fpp, you are on your own. I strongly suggest you to just get used to how the cpp looks like. Just let it be coloured in a different way and do not it change your mental parsing of the indentation levels. Your files are highly non-standard and unusual, especially with the block comments and I really have no other suggestion.